# Using pointers when finding largest sum of pairs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If this sounds like a homework question then that's fair since this is a midterm review question to work through to be more prepared for the quarter.

As an exercise, we're encouraged to find the largest sum of elements in an array and return that result. To better figure out how to do this I found a code example on the web that is in C++ rather than C. It goes like this for the function:

```
int findLargestSumPair(int arr[], int n)
{
    int first, second;
    if (arr[0] > arr[1])
    {
        first = arr[0];
        second = arr[1]; 
    }

    else
    {
        first = arr[1];
        second = arr[0];
    }

    //traverse remaining array and find first and second largest elements

    for (int i = 2; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > first)
        {
            second = first;
            first = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] > second && arr[i] != first)
            second = arr[i];
    }
    return (first + second);
}
```

So, if you called the function with something like,

```
int largestSum = findLargestSumPair(numberarray, numberarraylength);
```

...then that should store the value in `largestSum`.

But, if you want to store the *first and second largest numbers* in variables before they are summed together, then you'd have to load this function with two more parameters to be modified in the function, such as `first` and `second` being passed by `findLargestSumPair(int arr[], int n, int *first, int *second)`, and then at the end not returning anything because by using pointers they are changed by the function itself.

Am I on the right track that `int *first` and `int *second` is the right syntax for this, that they should be pointers in the definition of the function? Because I have tried to make that change and I get errors such as:

```
largestsum.c:3:6:note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
void findLargestSumPair(int arr[], int n, int *first, int *second)

warning: passing argument 4 of findLargestSumPair makes pointer from integer without a cast: findLargestSumPair(numbers, 9, largest, next_largest);
```

How am I using pointers incorrectly in this case to modify the values using the function rather than returning a result?

Comment: You apparently use the *third* argument correctly, what is the difference between the third and fourth argument in the call? Also, please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including *how* you call the function and which what values/arguments. Lastly, you *did* actually *read* the error message? What about it is hard to understand?

Comment: Sorry, I have a learning disability so it's sometimes hard going for me and learning programming. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 1):

Whatever I understood from your question, besides the largest sum, you also want to retrieve the largest and second largest number in the array.

You should make the following changes. The below function will return the largest sum and would give you the largest and second largest values as well.

```
void findLargestSumPair(int arr[], int n, int *largest, int *second_largest)
{
    ...
    ... // The same code what you have used above with below modication

    *largest = first;
    *second_largest = second;
    return (first + second);
}
```

Call the function as below:

```
int first, second;
lagest_sum = findLargestSumPair(arr, arr_len, &first, &second);
```

After the above call, you would largest value in the variable `first` and second largest in the variable `second`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is pass by reference. See the link for detailed explanation and example.
[Passing-arguments-by-reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

may this code can help you:
`

```
void setValue(int num, int *var)
{
    *var = num;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 0;
    setValue(2,&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

`
it is work fine on my computer, and the result was 2 as expected